# index.php returning a blank web page on openshift host

Tags: php, openshift

I have a website I am trying to maintain for a project:

http://uomtwittersearch-jbon0041.rhcloud.com/

The user connects to Twitter through the application and authenticates by using the twitteroauth library (by abraham). The process works fine up until it lands on index.php (calling index.inc as the respective HTML page) where it gives me a blank page. On localhost it works perfectly fine so I am not sure what could be causing this. Other pages such as connect.php initialize as required.

Visiting the website as it is will give an error and I am assuming that is because it cannot find index.php directly and it lies in the folder twitteroauth-master. I will fix this when I manage to at least make the contents of index.php appear but for now I am visiting:

http://uomtwittersearch-jbon0041.rhcloud.com/twitteroauth-master/connect.php

first, and this also goes to anyone who would like to visit it. If you have twitter log on with your details, this will move you to index.php which will be blank. Other than that one can simply replace 'connect' with 'index'.

**What could be causing the blank page for index.php?**

This is only my first ever web development project so I am not sure if this is something obvious. Moreover, I am using OpenShift for hosting.

**EDIT --------------------**

This is my index.php script. Again the script works fine without any problems on localhost.

```
<?php
//session_save_path(home/users/web/b2940/ipg.uomtwittersearchnet/cgi-bin/tmp);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start ();
require_once ('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once ('config.php');
include ('nlp/stop_words.php');
include ('nlp/acronyms.php');

set_time_limit ( 300 );

//////////////////////// TWITTEROAUTH /////////////////////////////////////

/* If access tokens are not available redirect to connect page. */
if (empty ( $_SESSION ['access_token'] ) || empty ( $_SESSION ['access_token'] ['oauth_token'] ) || empty ( $_SESSION ['access_token'] ['oauth_token_secret'] )) {
    header ( 'Location: ./clearsessions.php' );
}

/* Get user access tokens out of the session. */
$access_token = $_SESSION ['access_token'];



/* Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth ( CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token ['oauth_token'], $access_token ['oauth_token_secret'] );

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///// UNCOMMENT BELOW TO AUTOMATICALLY SPECIFY CURRENTLY LOGGED IN USER
//$user = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
//$user_handle = $user->screen_name;

$user_handle = 'AngeloDalli';

$timeline = getContent ( $connection, $user_handle, 1 );

$latest_id = $timeline [0]->id_str;
$most_recent = getMostRecentTweet ();

if ($latest_id > $most_recent) {
    $t_start = microtime(true); // start indexing
    $timeline = getContent ( $connection, $user_handle, 200 );
    $json_index = decodeIndex ();
    $json_index = updateIndex ( $timeline, $connection, $user_handle, $json_index, $most_recent );
    $json_index = sortIndex ( $json_index );
    $json = encodeIndex ( $json_index );
    updateMostRecentTweet ( $latest_id );
    $_SESSION ['index_size'] = countIndex ( $json_index );
    $t_end = microtime(true); // finish indexing
    $content = 'New tweets indexed! Number of tweets in index: ' . $_SESSION ['index_size'];
    // total indexing time
    $time = 'Total time of indexing: ' . ($t_end - $t_start)/60 . ' seconds';
} else {
    $content = 'No new tweets indexed!';
    $time = '';
}

/////////////////////// FUNCTIONS //////////////////////////////////////////////

function getContent($connection, $user_handle, $n) {
    $content = $connection->get ( 'statuses/user_timeline', array (
            'screen_name' => $user_handle,
            'count' => $n 
    ) );
    return $content;
}

function decodeIndex() {
    $string = file_get_contents ( INDEX_PATH );
    if ($string) {
        $json_index = json_decode ( $string, true );
    } else {
        $json_index = [ ];
    }
    return $json_index;
}

function updateIndex($timeline, $connection, $user_handle, $json_index, $most_recent) {
    // URL arrays for uClassify API calls
    $urls = [ ];
    $urls_id = [ ];

    // halt if no more new tweets are found
    $halt = false;
    // set to 1 to skip first tweet after 1st batch
    $j = 0;
    // count number of new tweets indexed
    $count = 0;
    while ( (count ( $timeline ) != 1 || $j == 0) && $halt == false ) {
        $no_of_tweets_in_batch = 0;
        $n = $j;
        while ( ($n < count ( $timeline )) && $halt == false ) {
            $tweet_id = $timeline [$n]->id_str;
            if ($tweet_id > $most_recent) {
                $text = $timeline [$n]->text;
                $tokens = parseTweet ( $text );
                $coord = extractLocation ( $timeline, $n );
                addSentimentURL ( $text, $tweet_id, $urls, $urls_id );
                $keywords = makeEntry ( $tokens, $tweet_id, $coord, $text );
                foreach ( $keywords as $type ) {
                    $json_index [] = $type;
                }
                $n ++;
                $no_of_tweets_in_batch ++;
            } else {
                $halt = true;
            }
        }
        if ($halt == false) {
            $tweet_id = $timeline [$n - 1]->id_str;

            $timeline = $connection->get ( 'statuses/user_timeline', array (
                    'screen_name' => $user_handle,
                    'count' => 200,
                    'max_id' => $tweet_id 
            ) );
            // skip 1st tweet after 1st batch
            $j = 1;
        }
        $count += $no_of_tweets_in_batch;
    }

    $json_index = extractSentiments ( $urls, $urls_id, $json_index );

    echo 'Number of tweets indexed: ' . ($count);
    return $json_index;
}

function parseTweet($tweet) {
    // find urls in tweet and remove (HTTP ONLY CURRENTLY)
    $tweet = preg_replace ( '/(http:\/\/[^\s]+)/', "", $tweet );

    // split tweet into tokens and clean
    $words = preg_split ( "/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/", $tweet );
    // /[\s,:.@#?!()-$%&^*;+=]+/ ------ Alternative regex

    $expansion = expandAcronyms ( $words );
    $tokens = removeStopWords ( $expansion );

    // convert to type-frequency array
    $tokens = array_filter ( $tokens );
    $tokens = array_count_values ( $tokens );

    return $tokens;
}

function expandAcronyms($terms) {
    $words = [ ];
    $acrok = array_keys ( $GLOBALS ['acronyms'] );
    $acrov = array_values ( $GLOBALS ['acronyms'] );
    for($i = 0; $i < count ( $terms ); $i ++) {
        $j = 0;
        $is_acronym = false;
        while ( $is_acronym == false && $j != count ( $acrok ) ) {
            if (strcasecmp ( $terms [$i], $acrok [$j] ) == 0) {
                $is_acronym = true;
                $expansion = $acrov [$j];
            }
            $j ++;
        }
        if ($is_acronym) {
            $expansion = preg_split ( "/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/", $expansion );
            foreach ( $expansion as $term ) {
                $words [] = $term;
            }
        } else {
            $words [] = $terms [$i];
        }
    }
    return $words;
}

function removeStopWords($words) {
    $tokens = [ ];
    for($i = 0; $i < count ( $words ); $i ++) {
        $is_stopword = false;
        $j = 0;
        while ( $is_stopword == false && $j != count ( $GLOBALS ['stop_words'] ) ) {
            if (strcasecmp ( $words [$i], $GLOBALS ['stop_words'] [$j] ) == 0) {
                $is_stopword = true;
            } else
                $j ++;
        }
        if (! $is_stopword) {
            $tokens [] = $words [$i];
        }
    }
    return $tokens;
}

function extractLocation($timeline, $n) {
    $geo = $timeline [$n]->place;
    if (! empty ( $geo )) {
        $place = $geo->full_name;
        $long = $geo->bounding_box->coordinates [0] [1] [0];
        $lat = $geo->bounding_box->coordinates [0] [1] [1];
        $coord = array (
                'place' => $place,
                'latitude' => $lat,
                'longitude' => $long 
        );
    } else {
        $coord = [ ];
    }
    return $coord;
}

function addSentimentURL($text, $tweet_id, &$urls, &$urls_id) {
    $urls_id [] = $tweet_id;
    $url = makeURLForAPICall ( $text );
    $urls [] = $url;
}

function makeURLForAPICall($tweet) {
    $tweet = str_replace ( ' ', '+', $tweet );
    $prefix = 'http://uclassify.com/browse/uClassify/Sentiment/ClassifyText?';
    $key = 'readkey=' . CLASSIFY_KEY . '&';
    $text = 'text=' . $tweet . '&';
    $version = 'version=1.01';
    $url = $prefix . $key . $text . $version;
    return $url;
}

function makeEntry($tokens, $tweet_id, $coord, $text) {
    $types = array ();
    while ( current ( $tokens ) ) {
        $key = key ( $tokens );
        array_push ( $types, array (
                'type' => $key,
                'frequency' => $tokens [$key],
                'tweet_id' => $tweet_id,
                'location' => $coord,
                'text' => $text 
        ) );
        next ( $tokens );
    }
    return $types;
}

function extractSentiments($urls, $urls_id, &$json_index) {
    $responses = multiHandle ( $urls );
    // add sentiments to all index entries
    foreach ( $json_index as $i => $term ) {
        $tweet_id = $term ['tweet_id'];
        foreach ( $urls_id as $j => $id ) {
            if ($tweet_id == $id) {
                $sentiment = parseSentiment ( $responses [$j] );
                $json_index [$i] ['sentiment'] = $sentiment;
            }
        }
    }
    return $json_index;
}

// - Without sentiment, indexing is performed at reasonable speed
// - With sentiment, very frequent API calls greatly reduce indexing speed
// - filegetcontents() for Sentiment API calls is too slow, therefore considered cURL
// - cURL is still too slow and indexing performance is still not good enough
// - therefore considered using multi cURL which is much faster than by just using cURL
// on its own and significantly improved sentiment extraction which in turn greatly
// improved indexing with sentiment
function multiHandle($urls) {

    // curl handles
    $curls = array ();

    // results returned in xml
    $xml = array ();

    // init multi handle
    $mh = curl_multi_init ();

    foreach ( $urls as $i => $d ) {
        // init curl handle
        $curls [$i] = curl_init ();

        $url = (is_array ( $d ) && ! empty ( $d ['url'] )) ? $d ['url'] : $d;

        // set url to curl handle
        curl_setopt ( $curls [$i], CURLOPT_URL, $url );

        // on success, return actual result rather than true
        curl_setopt ( $curls [$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

        // add curl handle to multi handle
        curl_multi_add_handle ( $mh, $curls [$i] );
    }

    // execute the handles
    $active = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec ( $mh, $active );
    } while ( $active > 0 );

    // get xml and flush handles
    foreach ( $curls as $i => $ch ) {
        $xml [$i] = curl_multi_getcontent ( $ch );
        curl_multi_remove_handle ( $mh, $ch );
    }

    // close multi handle
    curl_multi_close ( $mh );

    return $xml;
}

// SENTIMENT VALUES ON INDEX.JSON FOR THIS ASSIGNMENT ARE NOT CORRECT SINCE THE
// NUMBER OF API CALLS EXCEEDED 5000 ON THE DAY OF HANDING IN. ONCE THE API CALLS
// ARE ALLOWED AGAIN IT CLASSIFIES AS REQUIRED
function parseSentiment($xml) {
    $p = xml_parser_create ();
    xml_parse_into_struct ( $p, $xml, $vals, $index );
    xml_parser_free ( $p );
    $positivity = $vals [8] ['attributes'] ['P'];
    $negativity = 1 - $positivity;
    $sentiment = array (
            'pos' => $positivity,
            'neg' => $negativity 
    );
    return $sentiment;
}

function sortIndex($json_index) {
    $type = array ();
    $freq = array ();
    $id = array ();

    foreach ( $json_index as $key => $row ) {
        $type [$key] = $row ['type'];
        $freq [$key] = $row ['frequency'];
        $id [$key] = $row ['tweet_id'];
    }

    array_multisort ( $type, SORT_ASC | SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE, 
                      $freq, SORT_DESC, 
                      $id, SORT_ASC, 
                      $json_index );

    return $json_index;
}

function encodeIndex($json_index) {
    $json = json_encode ( $json_index, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );

    $index = fopen ( INDEX_PATH, 'w' );
    fwrite ( $index, $json );
    fclose ( $index );

    return $json;
}

function countIndex($json_index) {
    $tweets = [ ];
    $count = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count ( $json_index ); $i ++) {
        $id = $json_index [$i] ['tweet_id'];
        if (in_array ( $id, $tweets )) {
        } else {
            $tweets [] = $id;
            $count ++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

function lookup($array, $key, $val) {
    foreach ( $array as $item ) {
        if (isset ( $item [$key] ) && $item [$key] == $val) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function getMostRecentTweet() {
    $file = fopen ( 'latest.txt', 'r' );
    $most_recent = fgets ( $file );
    if (! $most_recent) {
        $most_recent = 0;
    }
    fclose ( $file );

    return $most_recent;
}

function updateMostRecentTweet($latest_id) {
    $file = fopen ( 'latest.txt', 'w' );
    fwrite ( $file, $latest_id . PHP_EOL );
    fclose ( $file );
}

include ('index.inc');
?>
```

Comment: Did you turn on errors at the top of your page? Sounds like it may be an error happening

Comment: I am afraid I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean maybe related to this http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php?

Again I am only beginning to scratch the real surface of web development so sorry for any stupid questions, and as always thank you for any help!

Comment: At the very top of your php page write `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I've tried adding the two lines you specified both above and below `session_start();` in index.php and it still gave me a blank page in both cases.

Comment: Can you supply some code for the index page? It's near impossible to tell what's going on without seeing what you have

Comment: Under this line `include ('nlp/acronyms.php');` write `echo true;` See if the page writes `1` at the top.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: I commented out all the functions and commented the appropriate code so that only a simple hello is outputted and it now shows. Does this mean that I have an error in one of my functions? I mean it doesn't make sense because it works on localhost!

Comment: @Rasclatt adding `echo true;` did not make a difference at first, but when commenting out the functions it outputted 1 on the browser along with the the intended HTML. But I don't understand how there could be something wrong in the functions as it works as required on localhost

Comment: One of the included page(s) you commented out has the error on it. You will need to go on to that page and see if there is an `error_reporting(0)` anywhere that is hiding errors. That will tell you where you need to make changes.

Comment: What do you mean by included pages? If I'm not mistaken the error is within index.php because when I commented its functions out it worked. You mean I should look into the functions to see if there is an error? And I am not sure what you mean because I didn't include `error_reporting(0)` on any of the scripts. I hope I am understanding you correctly, and again thank you for your continuous help!

Comment: Oh, it was a function on the index page. Gotcha. Ok well, you should have gotten an error message if you put `error_reporing(E_ALL)` at the top of the page. If it were me, I would try and find where you errors are being disabled so you can see what errors are happening. If you don't you are just shooting in the dark.

Comment: I have solved the issue, answer is below. Thank you for your help nonetheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. When creating my application on OpenShift using the application wizard, I was specifying **PHP 5.3** as the cartridge and not **PHP 5.4** (note the way I'm specifying certain empty arrays).

The true lesson to take from this is: **always be sure about the version of the language you're developing with**

Thank you for any help given and I hope this may come of use to someone else in the future!